# Component not being rendered in React after upgrading to Gatsby v.2 even though I'm getting no errors in Gatsby CLI

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I run`gatsby develop` I get **no errors** and the page shows everything but the navigation. While in the Chrome dev tools I'm getting this error: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`. The thing is I can't put together this error message with the issue I'm having.

**`src/layouts/index.js`**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

import Header from '../components/Header'

const Layout = ({ children, data }) => (
  <div>
    <Helmet
      title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
      meta={[
        { name: 'description', content: data.site.siteMetadata.description },
        { name: 'keywords', content: data.site.siteMetadata.keywords },
      ]}
    />
    <Header />
    {children()}
  </div>
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func,
}

export default Layout

export const query = graphql`
  query SiteTitleQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
        keywords
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**`src/components/Header.js`**

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import './Header.css'

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      hasScrolled: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  handleScroll = (event) => {
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset

    if (scrollTop > 50) {
      this.setState({ hasScrolled: true })
    } else {
      this.setState({ hasScrolled: false })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.hasScrolled ? 'Header HeaderScrolled' : 'Header'}>
        <div className="HeaderGroup">
          <Link to="/"><img src={require('../images/logo-designcode.svg')} width="30" /></Link>
          <Link to="/courses">Courses</Link>
          <Link to="/downloads">Downloads</Link>
          <Link to="/workshops">Workshops</Link>
          <Link to="/buy"><button>Buy</button></Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

This is my `gatsby info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 85.0.4183.102
    Safari: 13.1.2
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.24.55 => 2.24.56
    gatsby-link: ^2.4.13 => 2.4.13 => 2.4.13
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.3.10 => 3.3.10
    gatsby-plugin-styled-components: ^3.3.10 => 3.3.10
    gatsby-source-contentful: ^2.3.42 => 2.3.44
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.95
```

Comment: Why is `children` a function? I would not use it as a function and, also (not related to the issue) I would bind the correct context on the Header's constructor `this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no error, it is a warning as it is shown in the message. It doesn't block your rendering even it appears. This is a common warning that shows up in every loop that misses a `key` value in any React component. The `key` value must be unique and the purpose of using it is to help React to identify internally which items have changed (by adding/removing/re-ordering them). [This article may help you to clarify some stuff](https://medium.com/@adhithiravi/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists-dbb522188bbb).

For example:

```
{anyArray.map((item, index)=> <li key={item.value}>{item.value}</li>}
```

In the dummy example above, the `key` value is `item.value`. It's not recommended to use the `index` loop itself, however, you can append it to `item.value` if you want in order to avoid duplicated entries.

In addition, what I've found potentially code-breaking in your code is the usage of `window` without doing any validation before. As you can see in [Gatsby's documentation about global objects (debugging builds)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), since the code is compiled in the server, the usage of global objects such as `document` or `window` may break the code because they are not defined at the time your code is requesting it. To fix this, just add:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
    }
  }
```

Comment: If `window` is called inside `componentDidMount` it's not necessary to validate if it exists because `componentDidMount` happens on client side and `window` will already exist at that point.

Comment: It's a nice point @Mindastic. `componentDidMount` means that the DOM tree is loaded, no that the `window` is defined. Usually they  are related but not always.  It's plenty of exemples where the `window` object breaks the code inside a `useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount` lifecycle. I was only pointing a weak part. I've just added a way to fix if it breaks but as I said, it's a good point.